# Differentiable Non Linear Regressor to Be Used with CNN

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, nonlinear-regression

Is there a differentiable non-linear regressor?

I'm after a regressor which I can write in a few lines of PyTorch which is non linear and differentiable yest stronger than all simple to use activation layers.

The idea is to plug it after a very shallow CNN which will act as its feature extraction / dimensionality reduction pre process.

I know I can add layers ot the net and have similar effect but the problem I'm after has not many samples hence I want to keep the CNN with few parametrs (50-100) and have the regressor be something more advanced than few layers and differentiable yet with no need for *Training*.

Comment: Fully-connected layers with smooth activation functions?

Comment: I'm after something which isn't form the building blocks of a net. For instance, a Random Forest regressor (Yet it is not differentiable). Is there anything in the wild which is not NN based which is differentiable non linear regressor?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest considering a [Gaussian Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) regression (GPR).
GPR has all the properties asked for namely non-linear, good differentiability and working well with relatively small samples. In that sense, if we are really into it, we can affect the differentiability of the resulting GP too via the hyperparameters of its kernels (e.g. via controlling the $\nu$ degrees of a Matern kernel). There are quite a few implementations of GPs in Python; [`GPyTorch`](https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/index.html) seems the obvious one to try first if looking for something PyTorch based. Finally, it is worth mentioning there is a general view of "*Deep Neural Networks as Gaussian Processes*" by Li et al. (2018) in the work with [that same name](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00165) that provides a good theoretical background too; this work further generalised/extended in [*Neural Tangents: Fast and Easy Infinite Neural Networks in Python*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02803) by Novak et al. (2021).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a neural network as being layers of feature extraction followed by a regression on the extracted features. That is, it is common for the final hidden layer of a neural network to connect every neuron to the output neuron(s).

This is a generalized linear model on the final extracted features that are given in that last hidden layer.  The image below that [I posted yesterday](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/617489/247274) shows how this works for the final hidden layer and an output neuron.

[image]

However, nothing requires you to have that final regression be a linear model. Instead of $y = \sigma\left(
b +
\omega_{blue}x_{blue} +
\omega_{red}x_{red} +
\omega_{purple}x_{purple} +
\omega_{grey}x_{grey} 
\right)$, for some activation function $\sigma$, you could have something like $y = \sigma\left(
b +
\omega_{blue}x_{blue}^{\beta_{blue}} + 
\omega_{red}x_{red}^{\beta_{red}} +
\omega_{purple}x_{purple}^{\beta_{purple}} +
\omega_{grey}x_{grey}^{\beta_{grey}} 
\right)$. Then the final layer is a nonlinear regression but also differentiable.

Any differentiable nonlinear regression on that final set of extracted features (which will come from your convolutional layers) could be viable. I will give a few more examples below.

$$
y = \sigma\left(
\dfrac{
\omega_{blue}x_{blue} + \omega_{red}x_{red}
}{
\left(\omega_{purple}x_{purple}\right)^2 + \left(\omega_{grey}x_{grey}\right)^2 + 1
}
\right)
$$

$$
y = \sigma\left(
b +
\sin\left(\omega_{blue}x_{blue}\right) +
\omega_{red}x_{red} +
\omega_{purple}x_{purple} +
\omega_{grey}x_{grey} 
\right)
$$

$$
y = \sigma\left(
b +
\exp\left(\omega_{blue}x_{blue} +
\omega_{red}x_{red} +
\omega_{purple}x_{purple} +
\omega_{grey}x_{grey} \right)
\right)
$$

If you have an idea for a differentiable nonlinear regression on the neurons in the final hidden layer after your convolutional layers, the math says you can use it. You might lose the ability for your network to be a [universal approximator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), however.

Comment: I took the idea from DL but I'm after something which is beyond logistic regressor.

Comment: @EricJohnson It seems like I gave you examples beyond (generalized) linear models on the features extracted by the final hidden layer. Do you see something missing from this answer?

Comment: I meant that I know about stacking layers of DL framework. I am asking for something outside. Like, do we have a differential variant of decision tree? Or SVM?

Comment: It seems like, no matter what, you have to stick some kind of model on top of the final hidden layer (or maybe on earlier nodes). In that sense, stacking of some kind seems inevitable. @EricJohnson

Comment: I am after stacking something more complex. As I wrote. Beyond logistic regressor.

Comment: @EricJohnson So do it. The math makes perfect sense: your prediction is a complex, nonlinear function of the features extracted by the convolutional layers instead of a linear function of those features.

Comment: Read what I asked for. Something differentiable yet not the classic NN elements. Do you know such to stack? That's what I'm after.

Comment: @EricJohnson I posted multiple examples in my answer, such as $y = \sigma\left(
b +
\omega_{blue}x_{blue}^{\beta_{blue}} + 
\omega_{red}x_{red}^{\beta_{red}} +
\omega_{purple}x_{purple}^{\beta_{purple}} +
\omega_{grey}x_{grey}^{\beta_{grey}} 
\right)$.

Comment: It seems you didn't get what I'm after. I am not after the classic things as you posted them. I know them. I am after differentiable algorithms. Like the GP above. Do you have other example not built like just a neuron? Maybe a differentiable variant for trees, or SVM?

Comment: @EricJohnson You have features. Stick them in whatever model you want.

Comment: The idea is both will be optimized under the same loss function. The way you suggests means they are trained independently.

Comment: You can do the training simultaneously, just as you would for a more standard neural network. I don’t know how to implement it in software, but the math makes sense. It’s just an equation with parameters, and then you find the parameters that minimize some loss function.

Comment: You can't unless the added module is differentiable. Which is what I asked for. A differentiable formulation. Please read the question. What you suggest is not the direction. Having parameters in the objective, if the objective is not differentiable, won't help.